# Access Salesforce visualforce page in external website ( Using API or any other method )

Tags: salesforce

I have created a simple form ( using visual force page & apex class ) in salesforce.
Now I need to use that form as it is in my other web application.
Is there any way to do this? Using Salesforce API or any other method.

Comment: Using Site form.com 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose this page to unauthenticated users (guests) you can create a "[Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&type=5)" in Salesforce and add the page there. It's good for quick stuff, where you don't need a full-blown Site.com or customer/partner community solution. Then in that other page you could embed this as `<iframe>` or make yet another form that'd have `action` pointing to that VF page...

Comment: Thank you! But I don't want the form available to the public. If I create a site then that URL will be accessible by anyone.

Comment: You could hide the link to this form behind login on your website, maybe pass some secret parameter or check "refer(r)er" header maybe. Or consider creating SF community (there would be license cost) so it's still hidden behind login form but this time it's SF login. You didn't write enough details. Maybe what you need is to call your custom code as SOAP/REST API webservice? You'd make your own form and just send data to SF

Comment: I have created a simple quotation form that will generate a cost for selected products on salesforce. Now I want to use that form on my other website like myweb.com. But in an authenticated way.ie only users who have access to myweb.com can use the form on myweb.com.